# Save untested connection when testing is possible?

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, buttons, user-expectation, usability-testing

I have an admin console where I can add configure different data sources for my web application. The page looks like this :

[image]

Some of my queries are :

- What is the ideal scenario for test and save buttons?
- Should I allow connection to be saved without testing?
- How does it usually handled at backend and frontend?

Comment: I don't understand your first and third questions...

Comment: Edited to make the question more about the core problem here. "User Experience for..." is a redundant phrasing on this site. I appreciate there are other questions, but those are dependent on the crux of the interaction, which is whether or not you should force saving.

Comment: From my first question I just wanted to know how the industry usually does it, third question was more specific to any development details that might impact the user experience (for eg. some validations)

Answer (score 2):

#### What is the ideal scenario for test and save buttons?

Another way of approaching this is instead of having two separate buttons for 'test' and 'save', is to incorporate the test connection into the save functionality. This way it becomes more of a validation process (the system prevents you from failing) rather than putting the burden on the user to ensure it works.

#### Should I allow connection to be saved without testing?

If you follow the above process, then that solves this problem. However, even if the consequence of saving a connection that fails is minimal, it is not user centto allow them to do something that will cause an error in the future.

#### How does it usually handled at backend and frontend?

This will depend almost entirely on your specific configuration/scenario, and will not be able to be answered here.

Answer (score 1):

To answer one part of your question:

> Should I allow connection to be saved without testing?

A good design would probably be to **automatically test when the user presses save** (if it hasn't been tested already).

A related question is: **should you allow the source to be saved even if the test fails?**

I probably would allow this (with a confirmation dialog that warns the user).  Since, possibly the connection could be down, but the user knows it is correct and wants to save it anyway.

Comment: From my first question I just wanted to know how the industry usually does it, third question was more specific to any development details that might impact the user experience (for eg. some validations)